# Load Data Infile into mysql Table

Tags: mysql, file-upload

i m loading a text file into my mysql table through Load Data Infile. The text file records are inserting into table but 1st records is skipped.
My records into text file is separated by '#'. How this tokenizer breaks the complete line?

**Here is the info about my code and data**

**Records in text file looks like:-**

G#237662067259#237691052962#20190214#235939#000006#28#No_Digits#STAR_NO#1111111111
G#237661005122#237661000660#20190214#235946#000001#15#No_Digits#STAR_NO#1111111111

**I m using this query:-**
LOAD DATA INFILE 'D:/TP_CALLLOG_20190215.txt' INTO TABLE tbl_tp_calllog FIELDS TERMINATED BY '#' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';

[The Output of table is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/411Hd.png) 
and 
[i m expecting this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sviha.png)
Thnx for advance.

Comment: Please add table definition

Comment: You aren't loading id so I would specify the fields to be loaded.

Comment: Table definition is:-                                                                                  
    CREATE TABLE `tbl_crbt_calllog` (
  `id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `caller_no` VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `short_code` VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `call_date` VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `start_time` VARCHAR(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `end_time` VARCHAR(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `duration` VARCHAR(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
I have also specified the fields as well but that didn't work. Nd if i take that id field at last in the table then it is working fine, why so?

Comment: A common problem is not using the correct line terminators try '\r\n'. And why did you add a table definition for tbl_crbt_calllog when you are loading to tbl_tp_calllog? If these are in fact the same thing then you should get an error telling you there are more fiels in the infile than exist in the table.

Comment: I've also tried ''\r\n" and I've uploded this defination by mistake, but also for this table m facing the same issue. But when m removing id column from the table then it is working fine.

Comment: Do you get an error telling you there are more fields in the infile than exist in the table? I did and after adding some more fields to the table definition the file loaded fine. BTW are you on window, linux, mac or something else.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need '#' as Field Teminator? Did you try using comma','?

Comment: I have't  tried it but the separator of fields is #.